# Windows Media Player won't show DVD video when laptop is unplugged

Tags: windows, dvd, windows-media-player

I have a Dell Inspiron Mini 10 laptop running Windows XP.  Even though it doesn't have a DVD drive, using an ISO imaging tool I can mount DVD images as local drives.  I can then play DVD movies just fine using Windows Media Player, as long as the power cord is plugged in.  If unplugged WMP will only play audio and not video.

How can I fix this?  I'm not sure if the problem is with Windows Media Player or Windows XP.

Answer (score 1):

Check your power management options, normally accessed by right clicking in an empty area of your desktop and clicking Properties, sometimes under the Screensaver tab.  There may be options related to disabling certain features of your computer/graphics card/cpu whenever the laptop is running on batteries.

Comment: Certain GPUs will downthrottle on battery power as well.  This can often cause this sort of behavior.  I suggest checking Dell's proprietary power/battery management software as well.  (I don't use Dells but I /assume/ they have something of the sort)